# When i pass tuple into panda Dataframe, it splits it by default..how do i keep it in tuple?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I pass tuple into panda Dataframe, it splits it by default. How do I keep my data in original tuple form in the Dataframe?

```
stat_dic=pd.DataFrame(n)
```

n is list of the form `[(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)]`.
Pandas automatically splits the above list into 2 columns, whereas I want to keep it in one.

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame({'colname': n})`?

Comment: Works. I was just wondering why does it work after putting it in brackets?

Comment: @user159944 that is how pandas works , check the link http://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html

Comment: @zero although it seems simple, I would write it up as an answer. When I first saw this question, my instinct was to `df = pd.DataFrame(n, columns=['colname'])` which throws an error. Beyond that, my Google searches were not useful.